# Will slf4j instantiate the string in log.debug("I am here") if the logging level was INFO?

Tags: slf4j

Will slf4j instantiate the string in `log.debug("I am here")` if the logging level was `INFO`?

The back end logging API is Log4J.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string constant is always present, and it is just a reference passed in.

SLF4J will not *do* anything with the string passed if the logger is not enabled for that operation.